# Does sending two pageview in Universal Analytics generate errors?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm new to Google Analytics, and somehow it looks like there are two

> ga('send', 'pageview');

on the website. Does it generate errors in tracking? Or the .js is smart enough to figure out them?

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you call an error. Double tracking code will report the same number of sessions but double the number of pageviews (and will affect the bounce rate), but there will be no warning, thrown exceptions or anything that on a technical level would qualify as an error.